# Why is this java elegant pairing method not giving correct result?

Tags: java, algorithm, function, math

I'm pairing two numbers to form a unique number using elegant pairing. But when I pair two same numbers e.g "pair(12,12)" it gives me 156. When I want to unpair it, it's going to give me (0,12).
I then tried to pair (0,12), it gives me 156 also. 
All other numbers work gives a unique number, I can pair and unpair them unless I pair the same number; (10,10),(9,9), etc.

Where did I go wrong please?

```
public class elegantPairing {

    /**
    * @param x
    * @param y
    * @return 
    */
   public static int pair(int x, int y) {
    return x > y ? x * x + x + y : y * y + x;
   }

   public static int[] unpair(int z) {
       int b = (int) Math.sqrt(z);
       int a = z - b * b;
       return a < b ? new int[]{a, b} : new int[]{b, a - b};
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int firstValue = unpair(110)[0];
        int secondValue = unpair(110)[1];
        int paired=pair(10,10);
        System.out.println(firstValue+"     "+secondValue+"     Paired       "+paired);
   }

}
```

Comment: Should that condition be `x >= y ?...`?

Comment: You my friend, you're a life saver, been thinking about this for more than 40 minutes.  Make it an answer.

Comment: I'd rather not as it was a stab in the dark based on you saying that it doesn't work on equal arguments. I honestly don't understand what this code is supposed to do, and I don't like answering unless I can explain my answer. If you can explain why that change fixed it, it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Carcigenicate is right.

For the pair function, it takes the largest of the two numbers (say a) and produces a number that is bigger than (a) squared and less than (a + 1) squared, using one of two formulas, either (1) z = a * a + a + b or (2) z = a * a + b, where b is the smaller number of x and y.

You can check that either formula gives a number z that is bigger than (a) squared and less than (a + 1) squared.

So when you unpair, taking the square root of z always gives a, the larger of the original two numbers.

Suppose x > y.  Then the larger of the original numbers was x, so a = x and b = y, and a > b.
Then we used formula 1,

```
z = a * a + a + y
```

and

```
y = z - (a * a) - a
```

and we have (x, y) is (a, z - (a * a) - a)
That formula is the unpairing function for x > y and a > b.

Suppose x < y.  Then the larger of the original numbers was y, so a = y, and b = x and b < a.
Then we use formula 2,

```
z = a * a + x
```

and

```
x = z - (a * a)
```

and we have (x, y) is (b, z - (a * a))
That formula is the unpairing function for x < y and a > b, except with variables a and b switched in the unpairing function.

What about when x = y?
According to the unpairing function, the more complicated unpairing formula is used, the one corresponding to x > y and a > b.

So the original formula for x > y is the same for x = y, according to the unpairing function.  Which means the original pairing function should be:
x >= y ? x * x + x + y : y * y + x;